# Creating space time cube gives ERROR 110015 Unable to read input?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, space-time-cube

Somehow the create space time cube doesn't work on my project on Philadelphia crime data. The input feature is the point feature "robbery", I named the output as robbery_STC.nc, the time field is one field in the attribute table named dispatched date, all other blanks are left default.
The error message is:

> ERROR 110015, Unable to read the input space time cube; and failed to
>   execute (CreateTimeSpaceCube)

[image]

[image]